# Python printing issue in For loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to print a specific message for each item in my list using a for-loop. I am really not sure how to go about it. Thank you!

```py
pizzas = ['cheese', 'veggie', 'marherita']

for pizza in pizzas:

    print(f'{pizza(0)} is was my favorite as a child, \n {pizza(1)} is my favorite as an adult, but \n {pizza(2)} is also great!') # broken line of code
```

Error Message:

```
  File "c:/Users/logan/Untitled-2.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(f'{pizza(0)} is was my favorite as a child, \n {pizza(1)} is my favorite as an adult, but \n {pizza(2)} is also great!') # 
broken line of code
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What I want to print:

cheese was my favorite as a child,

veggie is my favorite as an adult, but

margherita is also great!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It does not let you post images yet to give you a hint that you should post text as text, not as an image.

Comment: What specific message do you want to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to stop the loop from printing for each item in the list, while using a for-loop, is by using a break: I need to do this is a for-loop per the book I'm learning from, Python Crash Course.

```
pizzas = ['cheese', 'veggie', 'margherita']


for pizza in pizzas:

    print(f'my favorite pizzas are: {pizzas}')
    break
```

This will print:

```
my favorite pizzas are: ['cheese', 'veggie', 'margherita']
```

or by removing the print for my favorite pizzas from the for-loop, as follows:

```
pizzas = ['cheese', 'veggie', 'margherita']


print(f'my favorite pizzas are:')


for pizza in pizzas:

    print(pizza)
```

This will print:

```
my favorite pizzas are:

cheese
veggie
margherita
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're new to Python. A print statement in a for loop does not have something in it that makes it print something depending on the text selected. You will need to use if statements.

```py
pizzas = ['cheese', 'veggie', 'margherita']

for pizza in pizzas:
    if pizza == "cheese":
        print(pizza + " was my favorite as a child,")
    elif pizza == "veggie":
        print(pizza + " is my favorite as an adult, but")
    elif pizza == "margherita":
        print(pizza + " is also great!")
```

By the way, in your print statement, there is no need of a for loop. You are trying to print it by referring to the pizza flavour in the list itself, not referring it in the actual for loop variable.